# Ogre program builds but crashes saying "Cannot find or open the PDB file"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ogre

```cpp
#include <OgreRoot.h>

#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include "windows.h"
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

#if OGRE_PLATFORM == OGRE_PLATFORM_WIN32
    INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR strCmdLine, INT )
#else
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
    {//main
        Ogre::Root* root = new Ogre::Root("plugins.cfg", "ogre.cfg", "Ogre.log");
        delete root;
        return 0;
    }//main
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The program builds successfully, but crashes when run, with the following message:

```
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\Ogre\Programs\NavProjectOgre\Debug\NavProjectOgre.exe', Symbols loaded.  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\Ogre\Programs\NavProjectOgre\Debug\OgreMain_d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2help.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'NavProjectOgre.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb in NavProjectOgre.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Ogre::FileNotFoundException at memory location 0x0012f46c..  
The program '[4240] NavProjectOgre.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Two things struck me:

1. The `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is supposed to be shown in a dull coloured font by Visual Studio because program control won't reach there, but it's shown in a normal coloured font. Something wrong?
2. Why is the program crashing when it built successfully?

Comment: Are you compiling using `Debug` configuration?

Comment: Yes. I had just built Ogre from source only for the Debug build settings of Ogre.sln. While building my app too, it's using the Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to point the project's configuration properties, Debugging, Working Directory to $(OGRE_HOME)\Bin\bin\$(Configuration)